# What is a good parallel program [with Java Thread]?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am learning Thread-ing in Java in order to create some program run in parallel. To design programs with parallelism is something I never had a chance to learn back at my school programming class. I know how to create threads and make them run, but I have no idea how to use them efficiently. After all I know it is not actually using threads that makes a program fast but a good parallel design. So I did some experiment to test my knowledge. However, my paralleled version actually runs slower than an unparalleled one. I start to doubt if I really get the idea. If you could be so kind, would you mind having a look my following program:

I made a program to fill an array in a divide-and-conquer fashion (I know Java has a Arrays.fill utility, but I just want to test my knowledge in multithreading):

```
public class ParalledFill
{
    private static fill(final double [] array, 
                        final double value, 
                        final int start, 
                        final int size)
    {
        if (size > 1000) 
        { // Each thread handles at most 1000 elements
            Runnable task = new Runnable() { // Fork the task
                public void run() { 
                    fill(array, value, start, 1000); // Fill the first 1000 elements
            }};
            // Create the thread
            Thread fork = new Thread(task);
            fork.start(); 
            // Fill the rest of the array
            fill(array, value, start+1000, size-1000);
            // Join the task
            try {
                fork.join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException except)
            {
                System.err.println(except);
            }
        }
        else 
        { // The array is small enough, fill it via a normal loop
            for (int i = start; i < size; ++i)
            array[i] = value;
        }
    } // fill

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        double [] bigArray = new double[1000*1000];
        double value = 3;
        fill(bigArray, value, 0, bigArray.length);
    }
}
```

I tested this program, but it turns out to be even slower than just doing something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bigArray.length; ++i)
    bigArray[i] = value;
```

I had my guess, it could be that java does some optimisation for filling an array using a loop which makes it much faster than my threaded version. But other than that, I feel more strongly that my way to handle threads/parallelism could be wrong. I have never designed anything using threads (always relied on compiler optimisation or OpenMP in C). Could anyone help me explain why my paralleled version isn’t faster? Was the program just too bad in terms of designing paralleled program?

Thanks,
Xing.

Comment: I don't quite understand how delegating work to a single `Thread` and then waiting for it to finish will ever be faster than just doing the work. I think you need to look at threading _patterns_ such as producer/consumer to get an idea of where to begin.

Comment: If you are concerned with efficiency, the main thing to remember is to test that using multiple threads actually helps.  Too often they are used and the overhead is so high that it is slower, sometime much slower.  In your example above, I suggest making sure you perform a write memory barrier otherwise you can get strange results.

Comment: When running two threads, you usually want both to do the same amount of work so they finish at the same time. I suggest giving half the work to your back ground thread.  BTW to minimise overhead I suggest using an ExecutorService as starting a thread can be very expensive depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Writing to memory is bandwidth intensive and using multiple threads is unlikely to help.  I suggest you start with a CPU intensive task which does use too much memory.

Comment: Lower your cpu to lowest power state and see if your one core versus multi core gained some speedup multiplier. Then you see if you stuck at memory bandwidth. Maybe you have an overclocked state cpu so only 1-2 cores can feed the memory controller fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have multiple CPUs, or long running tasks like I/O, I'm guessing that all you're doing is time slicing between threads.  If there's a single CPU that has so much work to do, adding threads doesn't decrease the work that has to be done.  All you end up doing is adding overhead due to context switching.

You ought to read "Java Concurrency In Practice".  Better to learn how to do things with the modern concurrency package rather than raw threads.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, especially pointing out add threads isn't helping. I had a look at the Fork/Join framework in JDK 7 which solves my problem.

Comment: Not without multiple CPUs.  let's assume that you have them.